# Convert Sql LIKE to Regex - Support All Wildcards

Tags: sql, regex, escaping

We want our app to enable End user typing some sql-like filters while we actually handle it by C# regex on the backend. Regular expression is a good choice.

I ran into some questions how to support %,_ and escaped [%] in the sql string.

I tried the solution from following URL, but it's not supporting escaped[%].

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36861/convert-sql-like-to-regex

for exmaple,
i want it to be True: "P90% Of People" like 'P90[%] Of%'.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, i figured it out:

```
public static bool ConvertSqlLikeToRegex(string left, string right)
        {
            var pattern = Regex.Replace(
                right,
                @"[%_]|\[[^]]*\]|[^%_[]+|[\s]*",
                m =>
                {
                    if (m.Value == "%")
                    {
                        return ".*";
                    }
                    else if (m.Value == "_")
                    {
                        return ".";
                    }
                    else if (m.Value.StartsWith("[") && m.Value.EndsWith("]"))
                    {
                        var wrappedValue = m.Value.Substring(1, m.Value.Length - 2);
                        if (wrappedValue.StartsWith("^"))
                        {
                            wrappedValue = wrappedValue.Substring(1, wrappedValue.Length - 1);
                            return "[^" + Regex.Escape(wrappedValue) + "]";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return Regex.Escape(wrappedValue);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var escaped = Regex.Escape(m.Value);
                        var nonWhiteSpaced = new Regex(@"\\\s|\\t").Replace(escaped, @"\s");
                        return nonWhiteSpaced;
                    }
                });
            return new Regex("^" + pattern + "$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch(left);
        }

    }
```